# JSF Argument Error: Parameter responseWriter is null

Tags: jsf, primefaces, shiro, omnifaces

I have a JSF2 webapp.
I get this error when my session has expired and i try to click on a p:commandButton (primefaces button)

I use Apache Shiro to access my website and I imagine that the login.xhtml page is called by it ..

I also use Ominfaces FullAjaxExceptionHandlerFactory, in fact the next error is the attempt to display the error page (Error.xhtml) but fails, due to a previus error

```
02-Jul-2019 09:45:51.002 GRAVE [http-nio-8080-exec-10] com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.handleRenderException Error Rendering View[/login.xhtml]
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Argument Error: Parameter responseWriter is null
    at com.sun.faces.util.Util.notNull(Util.java:448)
    at com.sun.faces.context.FacesContextImpl.setResponseWriter(FacesContextImpl.java:495)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.cleanupAfterView(PartialViewContextImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:331)
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContext.processPartial(PrimePartialViewContext.java:55)
    at javax.faces.context.PartialViewContextWrapper.processPartial(PartialViewContextWrapper.java:219)
    at org.omnifaces.context.OmniPartialViewContext.processPartial(OmniPartialViewContext.java:124)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.encodeChildren(UIViewRoot.java:1004)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:430)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:133)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at org.omnifaces.viewhandler.OmniViewHandler.renderView(OmniViewHandler.java:119)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:239)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:61)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:387)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.__invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:41002)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


02-Jul-2019 09:45:51.189 GRAVE [http-nio-8080-exec-10] org.omnifaces.exceptionhandler.FullAjaxExceptionHandler.logException FullAjaxExceptionHandler: An exception occurred during rendering JSF ajax response. Error page '/WEB-INF/error_pages/error.xhtml' will be shown.
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Argument Error: Parameter responseWriter is null
    at com.sun.faces.util.Util.notNull(Util.java:448)
```

I searched on google but without success, I need at least a trace to understand the type of error and direct my research on that

Comment: Hints: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info (the version info part, also for other libraries). Debug... (source of all is open). See where it is not null and where it becomes null. Tried without shiro? Without Omnifaces?

Comment: it seems to be apache shiro.. if i disable it then the error page is displayed..

Comment: This is debugging (root cause analysis) but then support stops from me since I do not use Shiro....